# Jenkinsfile agent "dockerfile" parameterized 'dir' argument

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a declarative pipeline with sequential stages in Jenkins 2.280.

The `dir` argument of `dockerfile` should be obtained from `${params}`:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  parameters {
    choice(name: PLATFORM, choices: ['dir1', 'dir2', ...], description: '')
    string(name: FOO, defaultValue: 1001, description: 'Interesting number')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Top') {
      agent {
        dockerfile {
          filename 'Dockerfile'
          dir 'platforms/${params.PLATFORM}'   // <-- HERE
          label 'master'
          additionalBuildArgs '--build-arg FOO=${params.FOO}'
          args '--mount type=bind,source=/opt/tools,target=/tools,readonly'
        }
      }  // agent
      stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
          steps { checkout scm }
        }
        stage('Build') {
          sh """
            // call cmake
            // call ninja
          """
        }
        ...
      } // stages
    } // Top
  } // stages
} // pipeline
```

This always seems to lead to a Java NoSuchFileException:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/<ws_name>/platforms/${params.PLATFORM}/Dockerfile
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
```

If I *hardcode* the `dir` argument to a valid directory name, then I run into issues with `FOO`:

```
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] sh
14:18:02  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/<ws_name>@tmp/durable-5884cc09/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/<ws_name>@tmp/durable-5884cc09/script.sh: Bad substitution
```

How can these two things be done?

Is there a better approach?

UPDATE: My problem was a "space" in the name of the pipeline project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create an example similar to you. Please take a look How the Docker file and dockerfile agent need to be used in declarative pipeline

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
ARG PACKAGE
RUN apk add ${PACKAGE}
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
  agent {
     dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile'
        dir "${params.DOCKERFILE_PATH}"
        additionalBuildArgs  "--build-arg PACKAGE=${params.PACKAGE}"
        args '-v /tmp:/tmp'
     }
   }
   parameters {
        string(name: 'DOCKERFILE_PATH', defaultValue: 'src01', description: 'Pick Dockerfile from a folder')
        text(name: 'PACKAGE', defaultValue: 'curl', description: 'Package To Be Installed')
   }
   stages {
     stage('build'){
        steps {
          sh 'git version'
        }
     } 
   }
}
```

groovy has to interpolate your runtime parameter and for that, you have to wrap it with `""`. `''` will not work

In your case, it will be

```
dockerfile {
    filename 'Dockerfile'
    dir "platforms/${params.PLATFORM}"
    label 'master'
    additionalBuildArgs "--build-arg FOO=${params.FOO}"
    args '--mount type=bind,source=/opt/tools,target=/tools,readonly'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @samit-kumar-patel. I'm trying to find time to get back to this to test it!

Comment: HI @samit-kumar-patel, after substituting double-quotes throughout, then after substituting values for variables, removing all scripts, removing comments, etc. so it was completely stripped ... I still hit the same error.  I renamed the project from "Foo Bar" to "Foo_Bar" and it worked!  Your answer didn't fix my problem but I will "accept" in nonetheless because you helped me!  Thanks!